# Java : method of a request attribute object is returning undefined ( STS Dynamic Web Project)

Tags: java, oop, web-applications, request, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS to create a Java webapp.
I have used the following code to set an attribute to an object of the Cat class named myCat.

```
request.setAttribute("myCat", myCat);
```

Inside of the Cat class are attributes and the method:

```
String showAffection(){
    return("jumps into your lap and stares at you.");
}
```

Now, in my .jsp file, I tried to print it with

```
request.getAttribute("myCat").showAffection();
```

However, STS is showing me this problem in the .jsp file:

> The method showAffection() is undefined for the type Object

What is going wrong? Is this not the correct way to access methods in the object?

Comment: you may need to cast the type of the object return from `getAttribute("myCat")` (which is `Object`) to the type which contains this `showAffection` method given that you know the actual type of object returned from `getAttribute("myCat")` that is... else utilise `instanceof` prior to performing casts.

Comment: Also, you really need to stop using scriptlets in JSPs. Learn the JSP EL. Learn the JSTL. Learn the Spring JSP tags.